# hover in hover jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a hover in a hover and when i hover the first element #rezultat it works correctly it shows me the id for every time i hover the element but when I hover its child it shows me the id of the child of the sum of all times I hovered the parent element before. Why? And what is the solution?

```
$("#rezultat").hover(function(event){
       console.log($(this).attr("id"));
       $("#rezultat").children().hover(function(){
             console.log($(this).attr("id"));
       });
});
```

Comment: look hire it is ibpm.net78.net/posteazasubiectnou.php you can see in the console the results

Comment: @jamal Don't force people to go on your site that might not be up in 10 years when someone else needs help with this same thing. Create a JSFiddle instead.

Comment: i don't know what is JSFiddle. i created this specially to show that it doesn't work.i dont forced you to go there.if you don't want to help, don't help

Comment: [This is JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this :

```
       $("#rezultat").hover(function(event){
   console.log($(this).attr("id"));
   $("#rezultat").children().hover(function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
         console.log($(this).attr("id"));
   });
 });
```

Comment: it doesn't work. look hire it is http://ibpm.net78.net/posteazasubiectnou.php   you can see in the console the results

Answer (score 0):

Keep both function calls separated:

```
$("#rezultat").hover(function(event) {
    console.log("parent: " + $(this).attr("id"));
});

$("#rezultat").children().hover(function() {
    console.log("child: " + $(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Otherwise you are assigning new onHover event to all children every time a hover event is triggered on the `#rezultat`.

Here is a working example: http://jsbin.com/vadameyexi/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: it doesn't work. look hire it is ibpm.net78.net/posteazasubiectnou.php you can see in the console the results

Comment: It works. I've added a link to a working example. Check your code again.